# No Data in Array after appending using Swift and xcode

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift

I am trying to download images from a url and then save them in an array of NSData.

I have a Class called Data Manager in which all my data is stored as well as functions for downloading images and getting data from URL.

In the same class I declare a variable called imageData of type [NSData] and let it equal an empty array as follows:

```
   var imageData: [NSData] = []
```

here is what my other 2 functions look like:

```
func getDataFromUrl(url:NSURL, completion: ((data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError? ) -> Void)) {
NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) in
completion(data: data, response: response, error: error)
}.resume()
}

func downloadImage(url: NSURL){
    print("Download Started")
    print("lastPathComponent: " + (url.lastPathComponent ?? ""))
    getDataFromUrl(url) { (data, response, error)  in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            guard let data = data where error == nil else { return }
            print(response?.suggestedFilename ?? "")
            print("Download Finished")
            self.imageData.append(data)
            print("you have \(self.imageData.count)")
        }
        print("you still do have \(self.imageData.count)")
    }
}
```

I call these functions in my app Delegate class under the function didFinishLaunchingWithOptions as so

```
let dataManager = DataManager()
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions      launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    dataManager.URLStringArray.removeAll()

  for url in dataManager.objects.imageURLS {
dataManager.URLStringArray.append(url)
  }
    for url in dataManager.URLStringArray {   
    dataManager.downloadImage(NSURL(string: url)!)
    print(url)
    }

return true
}
```

In my view controller I go to get the data in the image array via following function:

```
func returnImageData() -> [NSData] {
    print("your image count is \(imageData.count))")
    return imageData
}
```

but the array is empty! Even though through the whole process I noticed that the array was becoming larger and larger because the print to the logs were showing the array increasing!

Thanks!

Comment: There's `self.imageData` and `self.ImageData` in this excerpt, I hope it's not like that in your real code, that could be the issue.

Comment: In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` if you remove all items from `URLStringArray` then the following repeat loop will be skipped.

Comment: the "imageData" and "ImageData" were typos, in my code there are all the same

Comment: @vadian , the remove all items is called before the loop starts, once the loops starts and  the URLS are being appended it is never called.

Comment: This is confusing. After removing all items from `URLStringArray` there is nothing to enumerate.

Comment: Sorry, the way I set it up might be confusing. I have a data set with each instance having a string value which is a URL. The URLStringArray is an empty string array. Ex. var URLStringArray:[String] = [""]. Before I fill it with the URLS that will be used to download the data, I clear the array and then append each string from each instance of my objects to the URLStringArray. I can see why you are confused, the code I provided does not reflect this, Thanks for pointing it. I will check tonight whether this is actually I had set it up

Comment: @vadian I fixed the code, I think it should look like this? I haven't yet upodated it on xcode since Im not home but do you think this should work?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using async call to download the image data, at the the time you are printing the count of the imageData the image is not yet downloaded and so the array is not yet populated. Of course this is assuming that you are using the right property names as Eric.D has pointed out.

Comment: The count of the image data is printing to the logs and it is increasing. However, when I go into my view controller and call the method to get the array in view did load, and then try to populate the array but it shows up as an empty array. I have tried so many different ways of getting this data but it always ends up in an empty array!

Comment: returnImageData() is in ViewController, Right? Is there a imageData array in the ViewController too. Shouldn't it return `dataManager.imageData`

Comment: the issue was I needed to create a variable in my singleton instance and then append the images to that and retrieve it

Comment: If your dataManager is a singleton and no instance of that is created elsewhere then you can use it as I've mentioned in my comment earlier.